# RDC session being automatically ended

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I have a windows 2008 server and if I connect to it using RDC and I close my session (NOT logging off) the server automatically signs off, I don't want this to happen. I need it to leave my session alive, with the programs running that I open when I am connected.

How can I set the server to not sign out my user after I close RDC?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Administrative tools -> Terminal Services -> Terminal Services Configuration.  From the Connections section, right-click on the RDP-tcp connection type & select "Properties".

Select the "Sessions" tab, and check to see if there is an override specified for "End a disconnected session".  If it is, change this to "Never", or uncheck the override checkbox.

Comment: I would also make sure you don't have a GPO that might be applying this setting.